# where should i add the django rest framework token in http. header or body?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-login

Im a new in django rest framework. im developing a user registration, login and logout page for first. in many of the tutorial i found that, they add the token in the body. but in the drf documentation , they it shoud be in the body. im so confuced. anyone help me with the logic

i just created a login page. the view is testing the username and the password then return user information and the token. but how do i return the token. here is my login view. can u review my code:

````
# user login
class user_login(APIView):
    serializer_class = login_serializer

    def post(self, request, format = None):
        print(request.data)
        """
        serialing the data and validating it, any exception found is_valied()
        the functionn automatically return respond with the error message as a dictionery
        """

        # serializing data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        # validating the data
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        # authenticate the user
        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        password = serializer.validated_data['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email = email, password = password)
        
        # if user is authenticated create tocken
        if user:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
            print(request.user)
            print(request.auth)
            return Response({"status":200, "email": email, "token": token.key}, status=200)

        # else return 401 unautherized message
        else:
            return Response({"status":401,"message":"unauthorized"}, status=401)   ```
````

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that token? If many tutorials tells you to "add" it to the body, but any other documentation tells you the same, what's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Browsers don't expose that to clients for security purposes but you can use a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or it's alternatives to do that.
after sending the login post request and you get your token key,
copy it and paste in the authorization header and enter "token" first space the paste the token.
NB enter token without the double quotes

Comment: So, should every user of that website now download Postman to gather the token?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35084402)

Comment: No users don't need that it is only for development. It is in your Front-End development(React,Next,Vite or whatever front-end framework or tool you are using) that you fetch data from the API you already created in the Back-End and use the tool to display it. and to fetch you need to add the authorization token you got in the request header, this is done by the browser using the code specified in the front-end app